# How do I duplicate an item without commands in Minecraft?

Tags: minecraft-bedrock-edition

I am in Creative mode in my friend's server, but I do not have commands

How do I simply duplicate an item (with NBT tags) that is in my inventory easily?

I would prefer a method without the use of glitches.

Answer (score 4):

Get a shulker box in creative place the item you want to duplicate in it also grab a pickaxe and place down the shulker box and put the item you want to duplicate in it go to survival then mine the shulker then go back to creative and then you can place the shulker as many times as you want with the items in it

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately, it is not possible to do this. However, you can put the items that you want to duplicate in a chest, and `/clone` it.

For example, you want to duplicate a Sharpness V diamond sword that is named "Bob." You put the sword in a chest (let's say that the chest's coordinates are at `0 64 0`). To duplicate the chest and put it at `2 64 0`, you run this command, either through chat or a command block:

```
/clone 0 64 0 0 64 0 2 64 0
```

You can even put multiple items in the chest and they will ALL be duplicated at once! I hope this helps.

Comment: I did mention that i dont have commands, so sorry it doesnt, but thanks for the help once i get commands.

Answer (score 2):

1. Open the inventory.
2. Click on the item you want to duplicate to pick it up.
3. Hold your mouse's scroll wheel button and drag it over empty inventory slots to duplicate it as stacks in your inventory.

Comment: @ExpertCoder14 Yes, that makes for sense. I’ll just delete the first comment. Thanks for explaining it.

Answer (score 1):

Don't quote me on this, but I am pretty sure if you click your pick block button and hold Control, it will save all of its NBT tags with it.

Comment: Incorrect. It is true that this works for picking *blocks*, but with *items in the inventory*, it's not possible.

Comment: @ExpertCoder14 actually that would be fine!